# Documents with Tags model in IndexedDB

Tags: nosql, database-schema, indexeddb

I have songs and tags. A tag can be of a type like "recording location" or "last recording date".

In a relational model I would have a join model that hold song_id and tag_id infos. But in a document base DB like indexeddb I would store the tags and their infos directly in the document. I wonder if that would not lead to DB bload in the long run if I do not have many unique tags?

If another song would require one of the tags, that are already used on another song, I would have a duplicate tag.

I could of course go with a join store here too, but this would then also include manual fetches over 2 tables.

I have several questions to the model:

1. Should I have a songs and a tags store?
2. How are bulk updates of tags, that a attached to each song performed?
3. What indices would I probably need to make this fast?

My main aspect is to search via tag values (and filtered by type).

Answer (score 1):

The key with using IDB and other NoSQL stores well is not getting caught up in join ids, and just trying to make each object store useful in its own right. (And using indexes well!) Remember this is just how SQL-ish databases work under the hood, but it allows you to do specialized joins *when you need it* rather than in the general case.

Bulk updates are more of a challenge but this is more about optimizing for the most common case (showing looking up songs/tags) than optimizing for more rare things (bulk-changing tag names)

The most basic schema you're looking at is storing songs as something like:

```
{ name: "Name of Song"
  id: <song id>
  tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"] }
```

And tags can simply be id'd by their name:

```
{ name: "tagname"
  description: "Some tag description or whatever" }
```

First create your song objectStore:

```
var songs = db.createObjectStore("songs", "id");
```

Then create an multiEntry index:

```
songs.createIndex("tags", "tags", {multiEntry: true});
```

Then create a tag objectStore:

```
var tags = db.createObjectStore("tags", "name");
```

Now you can do the joins yourself if you really need to, but sometimes it's just some on-off stuff.

```
var trans = db.transaction(["songs", "tags"]);

var songTags = [];
trans.objectStore("songs").get("songid").onsuccess = function(e) {
    var song = e.target.result;
    for (var i = 0; i < song.tags.length; i++) {
        trans.objectStore("tags").get(song.tags[i]).onsuccess = function(e) {
            var tag = e.target.result;
            songTags.push(tag);
        }
    }
}
trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
     showSongTags(songTags);
}
```

Thanks to the 'tags' index on songs, the reverse is pretty easy too. Note that we're using tag names directly, not messing around with some intermediate numeric tag_id.

```
var trans = db.transaction(["songs", "tags"]);

var songs = [];
trans.objectStore("songs").index("tags").openCursor("tag1").onsuccess = function(e) {
    var cursor = e.target.result;
    if (!cursor) return;

    cursor.continue();
    songs.push(cursor.value);
}
trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
     showSongs(songs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically facing the same problem people face when they have to choose between a relational database like MySQL and a document-oriented one like MongoDB. Duplicating data -- not to mention the keys themselves -- take up space and it's definitely more "third form"ish to store one copy and use foreign keys instead.

That said, I've been through both sides of this in my IndexedDB work. Believing the same thing you do -- regarding storage efficiency -- needs to be weighed against the way you're actually accessing the data. When you want to achieve foreign key-like schema in IndexedDB it necessarily requires 2 plus object stores, like stored as two separate files on the underlying filesystem. That means for each query that you want foreign key data (here, tags) you have to have at least two object store hits, probably two transactions and, I'm assuming, the extra io overhead and such associated with those.

I'd go with the document-oriented approach and try to make the storage hit less severe with tricks like key shorthand (e.g. "n" instead of "name).